# Does Instance Variables of a module shared between class with the mixin?

Tags: ruby, variables, scope, instance, mixins

I want to know how the instance variables of a Ruby module behaves across multiple classes which 'mix' it 'in'. I wrote a sample code to test it:

```
# Here is a module I created with one instance variable and two instance methods.
module SharedVar
  @color = 'red'
  def change_color(new_color)
    @color = new_color
  end
  def show_color
    puts @color
  end
end

class Example1
  include SharedVar
  def initialize(name)
    @name     = name
  end
end

class Example2
  include SharedVar
  def initialize(name)
    @name     = name
  end
end

ex1 = Example1.new("Bicylops")
ex2 = Example2.new("Cool")

# There is neither output or complains about the following method call.
ex1.show_color
ex1.change_color('black')
ex2.show_color
```

Why it doesn't work? And Could someone explain what will the actual behavior of `@color` across multiple `Example$` instances?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ruby modules and classes are objects, so it's possible to set instance variables for them.

```
module Test
  @test = 'red'
  def self.print_test
    puts @test
  end
end

Test.print_test #=> red
```

Your mistake is thinking that the variable @color is the same for:

```
module SharedVar
  @color
end
```

and

```
module SharedVar
  def show_color
    @color
  end
end
```

which is not.

In the first example, the instance variable belongs to the `SharedVar` object and in the second example the instance variable belongs to the object you include the module in.

Another explanation by **self** pointer. In the first example the **self** pointer is set to the module object `SharedVar`, so typing `@color` will refer to the object `SharedVar` and there's no connection with another object. In the second example, the method `show_color` can be called only on some object, i.e. `ex1.show_color`, so the **self** pointer will point to `ex1` object. So in this case the instance variable will refer to `ex1` object.

Comment: Quite clear explanation! So if the module I designed is for mixing with other class. I should define the `instance variable` inside `instance method`, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, just compute what is the current self and then you can understand where the instance variable will be placed.

Comment: Thanks. I am just learning Ruby currently, not to the `current self` part. Seems more elegant language than `javaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

You have included a module in to a class.. so the instance variable @color should be an instance variable of both the class Example1 and Example2

So if you want to access the @color variable means you suppose to create an object to the class and then you can accesss it

For Ex

```
irb(main):028:0> ex1.change_color('black')
=> "black"
irb(main):029:0> ex1.show_color
black
irb(main):031:0> ex2.change_color('red')
=> "red"
irb(main):032:0> ex2.show_color
red
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. But both `ex1` and `ex2` doesn't have `color` defined.